# Setting up X11 forwarding via plink in Tramp

Tags: emacs, putty, x11-forwarding, emacsw32

I've been trying to use TRAMP to remotely access some servers at work. I'm trying to connect to a remote server via Emacs to edit R files and run an R session remotely.

My set-up is as follows:

- My machine is running Windows 7 with Emacs 24.2.1, Xming 7.5.062 and PuTTY 0.62
- The server is running Red Hat 5.8

The relevant part of my .emacs file is:

```
(require 'tramp)
(setq tramp-default-method "plink")
(setq ssh-explicit-args '("-ssh -X"))
(setq explicit-shell-file-name '"/bin/zsh")
```

I am able to remotely connect, edit files, and run a shell but I can't get the server to open up windows on my window machine. I have access control off on the Xming instance on my Windows machine and if I use PuTTY to open a remote session I can get X windows working remotely. The problem is when I use plink via Emacs/TRAMP.

Thanks,